# how do i fix this error- Cannot convert value of type 'UIImageView' to expected argument type 'UIImage' in the following code

Tags: swift

```
import UIKit

class UserVC: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var userImagePicker: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var usernameField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var completeSignInBtn: UIButton!

    var userUid: String!
    var emailField: String!
    var passwordField: String!
    var imagePicker: UIImagePickerController!
    var imageSelected = false
    var username: String!

    func uploadImg() {
        if usernameField.text == nil {
            print("Must have username")
            completeSignInBtn.isEnabled = false
        }else {
            username = usernameField.text
            completeSignInBtn.isEnabled = true
        }
        guard let img = userImagePicker, imageSelected == true else {
            print("image must be selected")
            return
        }

        // below is where the error is can you help me? 
        if let imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 0.2) {
            let imgUid = NSUUID().uuidString
            let metadata = StorageMetadata()
            metadata.contentType = "img/jpeg"

            Storage.storage().reference().child(imgUid).put(imgData, metadata: metadata) {
                (Metadata, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print("did not upload image")
                }else {
                    print("uploaded")
                    //
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have no Idea on how to fix this error. If there is anyone out there that can help, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: You're doing `guard let img = userImagePicker`, this is your mistake. Your "img" is not an image. Then later you use "img" as an image, so it fails, of course. Get the image from the object instead of the object itself.

Answer (score 0):

As I see from the outlet `userImagePicker` is a `UIImageView` not `UIImage`

so to fix the issue I would suggest taking the image from the view by:

changing this line

```
guard let img = userImagePicker, imageSelected == true else {
```

to this

```
guard let img = userImagePicker.image, imageSelected == true else {
```

assuming that the image is loaded to view after picking it from `UIImagePickerController`